# Is it possible to force focus on CommonOpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to use the CommonOpenFileDialog in a WinForm application, I would like that the users stay on the dialog until a folder is selected or eventually closed the dialog manually

```
if (setTexturesFolderDialog != null)
{         
    setTexturesFolderDialog.Focus(); //this do not exist
    return;
}

setTexturesFolderDialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog()
{
    IsFolderPicker = true
};
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Sounds like it would make your users feel helpless or annoyed if they decide that something else is more important than your program just at the moment.

Comment: ShowDialog() already ensures that the dialog has the focus, no extra help is needed.  This *can* go wrong if the UI is not designed correctly.  A dialog always needs a parent window to stay on top of.  Or this code runs on a worker thread, never do that.